# How to retrieve data from dynamically generated UITextField s?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, view

I am developing an app, which needs to generate UI components dynamically based on the data returned from the server.
I achieved dynamic layout by generating the UILabels, UITextFields, UIPickerViews, etc. dynamically in code
Eg:

```
for(int i=0; i < count; i++)
{
    UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 30)];
    txtField.placeholder = [@"Test Input" ];

    [self.view addSubview:txtField];
}
```

Now, my question is, how do i retrieve the input the user enters in the text field. Coz, i dont have a way to map this text field to a variable in my model object.
I am considering KVOs as an option, but wanted to do my due diligence and check if there was a more straightforward way of achieving this.

Thank you,
cybervedaa

Comment: Do you really mean to be creating multiple text fields with exactly the same frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `< UITextFieldDelegate >`. Make yourself the delegate of `txtField`. Set the `tag` of `txtField`. Then when you receive a callback to `textFieldDidEndEditing:` or perhaps `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` you can tell which text field has been changed and do something about it.

Comment: I believe you should be able to "map the text field to a variable in your model object" using the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method that @Wain suggests.  Then, whenever you need to use what is in the text field, look at whatever you mapped it to in your model.  At least I'm pretty sure that the best practice way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

To reference the views you need to reference them somehow. When using interface builder, for example, the views are referenced via properties of your class specified with `IBOutlet`. Since you are creating these views in a loop I recommend that you tag each view and retrieve them using [`viewWithTag:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html). Be careful of other views having a default tag of 0 so increase the index to keep the value unique.

```
for(int i=0; i < count; i++)
{
    UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 30)];
    txtField.placeholder = [@"Test Input" ];
    txtField.tag = i + 1;

    [self.view addSubview:txtField];
}

//To retrieve elsewhere
UITextField *txtField = [self.view viewWithTag:index];
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's dynamically generated give each textField a unique tag and then use it to fetch the values from it.

```
UITextField *textField = [self.view viewWithTag:uniqueTag];
```